# Remote NRPE agent not getting arguments from Nagios server

Tags: debian, nagios, nrpe

I have configured `Nagios Core server` (4.4.5) with `nagios-plugins-release-2.2.1` and `nrpe-nrpe-3.2.0` plugging. I use Debian (Stretch).

I manage to get `server load` stats from remote server using `nrpe` without using arguments. I simply use below line in remote server's `nrpe.cfg` file.

```
command[check_load]=/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_load -r -w 0.75,0.5,0.3 -c 1,0.75,0.5
```

This working fine.

But I'm unable to use arguments with check_nrpe command and mostly get error like `NRPE: Command 'check_load!0.75,0.5,0.3!0.1,0.75,0.5' not defined`.

I tried below,

Below command in remote agent `nrpe.cfg`,

```
command[check_load]=/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_load -r -w $ARG1$ -c $ARG2$
```

Below command in `command.cfg` file in Nagios server,

```
define command {
    command_name    check_nrpe
    command_line    $USER1$/check_nrpe -H $HOSTADDRESS$ -c $ARG1$ -a $ARG2$
}
```

And below config in services.cfg

```
define service {
        use                     box-service
        hostgroup_name          allpublic
        service_description     Server Load
        check_command           check_nrpe!check_load!'0.75,0.5,0.3 0.1,0.75,0.5'
}
```

Note that `dont_blame_nrpe=1` been done in those remote agent and nagios server and allow IPs correctly.

I wonder why args are not work with my setup. Did I miss any packages to install? In remote agent I installed below packages.

```
apt install -y nagios-nrpe-server nagios-plugins
```

Appreciate some help.

Comment: Try with `check_command           check_nrpe!check_load!0.75,0.5,0.3 0.1,0.75,0.5`

Comment: I tried that, it gives 'NRPE: Command 'check_load!0.75,0.5,0.3!0.1,0.75,0.5' not defined'

Comment: Okey, try something like this on remoted server: `/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_nrpe -H 127.0.0.1 -c check_load -a 0.1,0.5,0.2 0.75,0.5,0.3`

Comment: Thanks but still the same.

Comment: If you restart the remote NRPE, do you see something like: `nrpe[26964]: Warning: Daemon is configured to accept command arguments from clients!` in `/var/log/messages`?